# UIButton disappear when I add AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer to my UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton

I've added a view to my viewcontroller, and added a record button to my view in Interface builder. Programmatically, I initialize the `AVCaptureVideoPreview` layer and add it to my `view.layer`. Once I run, I see the camera working on my screen, but no button. I have to add the button using `[myView addSubview:self.record]`, then I see it. I checked my Interface builder, and the button is opaque, but it still won't show until I add it in the code.

Any thoughts??

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

That's because you're adding AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer probably in viewDidLoad of you view controller, where all the views from IB are already loaded, so it covers the UIButton - you're adding this layer on top of current layer (with your views from storyboard/interface builder). The solution is to create a container for the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer and add it as a sublayer of the container. Your button and container view have to be siblings in view hierarchy. More over, button has to be placed on top of the container.

```
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *captureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];
[self.containerView.layer addSublayer:captureVideoPreviewLayer];
```

This is the view hierarchy from storyboard:

[image: view hierarchy]

Answer (score 0):

Use layer.insertSublayer(..., above: ...) to insert your layer above the video layer.

Here's a bit more detailed instructions for Swift how to insert image on the top of video stream [link](http://www.mikitamanko.com/blog/2017/08/04/swift-put-overlay-on-top-of-avcapturevideopreviewlayer/#more-381)